# SQL JOIN with 2 column(nullable) referencing to same foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below two tables-
SystemField
[image]

Anlother Table- SystemFieldMapping
[image]

I want to get data and have same number of rows as of SystemFieldMapping table by below query-

```
SELECT m.id,m.field1_id,m.field2_id,f1.name as f1_name,f2.name as f2_name
FROM SystemFieldMapping m
JOIN SystemField f1 ON f1.id=m.field1_id OR m.field1_id IS NULL
JOIN SystemField f2 ON f2.id=m.field2_id OR m.field2_id IS NULL
```

Issue is I am getting 4 records in output, instead of single record(since SystemFieldMapping table has only one record). SQL Fiddle link-
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/279fb/1

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't use markup, it uses markdown for formatting. Also, things like DDL and DML should be in your question as well, not in an external link. Links should compliment the question, but not be required.

Comment: One point (you may not have control over): Having table attributes with the same name, save for a number (e.g. `field1_id` and `field2_id`) is generally a bit of a code smell, indicating your data's not optimally normalized. What if you need to add a `field3_id`? Or an arbitrary number of fields? I would think a better solution might be for your `SystemMappingField` table to just have an `id` and `field_id` attribute. Then you could use a pivot (with or without dynamic SQL) to "recreate" 1 row for each row in the SystemFieldMapping table.

Comment: @Larnu - Sure, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT m.id, m.field1_id, m.field2_id,
       f1.name as f1_name, f2.name as f2_name
FROM SystemFieldMapping m LEFT JOIN
     SystemField f1
     ON f1.id = m.field1_id LEFT JOIN
     SystemField f2
     ON f2.id=m.field2_id ;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/279fb/4) is the SQL Fiddle.